# How can i write in NodeJS with MongoDB the following MySQL Select?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

What i want to:

```
SELECT MAX(pieces) //(to a var variable)
FROM record
WHERE ip = :ipAddress AND filename_full = :filename
```

:ipAddress and filename come via the http...Thanks for the help

[the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RghsT.png)

where I want to use:

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB', function(err,db){
    if(!err){
        acl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db, 'acl_'));
        acl.allow('guest', 'business', 'view');

        console.log(acl);
        var cursor = db.collection('record').find({ip: ipAddress, filename_full: filename});
        cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            if (doc != null) {
                console.dir(doc);
            } else {
                console.log("Not found");
                callback();
            }
        });*/

        }
});
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/ As is this: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Mongoose**, it help you to work with MongoDB easier.

```
Record.findOne({
    ip: ipAdress,
    filename_full: filename
}).sort({
    'pieces': -1
}).exec(function(err, doc) {

});
```

Reference: [Mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) , [Get max value in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572592/get-max-value-in-mongoose)

Comment: Record.find([{ 'ip': ipAddress},{ 'filename_full': filename}])
                .sort({'pieces':-1})
                .limit(1)
                .exec(function (err, recordFinal) {
                    if (err){
                        res.send(err);
                    console.log("PIECES: ",recordFinal.pieces);
                    });

Comment: but it give me an object with the full details not just the pieces...how can i do that it is just give me the pieces integer?

Comment: and write that the recordFinal.pieces is undefined

Comment: Use `findOne` here instead of `find`, otherwise `doc` is an array instead of the single doc you're looking for.

Comment: Thank @JohnnyHK for your suggestion.